# Don't allow hyper-v container to access host's network

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

Is it possible to still be connected to the internet in a hyper-v Windows 10 container, but not have access to any other device on the host's network?

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of virtual network which can be created: External, Internal and Private. Two of the virtual network types can connect to the external network, but they can all connect to the network where the host is located. They are External and Internal.

**External**

External virtual networks are used where you want to allow communications between

- Virtual machine to virtual machine on the same physical server
- Virtual machine to parent partition (and vice-versa)
- Virtual machine to externally located servers (and vice-versa)
- (Optional) Parent partition to externally located servers (and vice-versa)

**Internal**

Internal virtual networks are used where you want to allow communications between

- Virtual machine to virtual machine on the same physical server
- Virtual machine to parent partition (and vice-versa)

**Private**

Private virtual networks are used where you want to allow communications between

- Virtual machine to virtual machine on the same physical server

For details about virtual network types we can refer the following articles:

[Hyper-V: What are the uses for different types of virtual networks?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jhoward/2008/06/17/hyper-v-what-are-the-uses-for-different-types-of-virtual-networks/)

[Step by Step Guide to Configure Windows Hyper-V Virtual Network](http://www.hyper-v-mart.com/HowTo/Configure_HyperV_Virtual_Network.aspx)